# How to prove $k^n \equiv 1 \pmod {k-1}$ (by induction)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

How to prove $k^n \equiv 1 \pmod {k-1}$ (by induction)?

Comment: **HINT** It's equivalent to proving $\rm\ 1^{\:n}\equiv 1\ $ by modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'll leave the case of $n=1$ to you.

So, for a fixed $k$, suppose that $k^n\equiv 1 \mod(k-1)$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

We want to show that $k^{n+1} \equiv 1 \mod(k-1)$.  Well, $k^{n+1}=k^n k$, and we know that $k^n\equiv 1 \mod(k-1)$ (since this is the induction hypothesis).  So, what is $k^{n+1}$ congruent to mod $k-1$?

Comment: What you think about following proof? 
Let us suppose that for some n
$k^n \equiv 1 \pmod {k-1}$. One has to show that 
$k^{n+1} \equiv 1 \pmod {k-1}$.
Now because $k^{n+1}=k^n \cdot k \equiv 1 \cdot k \equiv 1 \pmod {k-1}$(because $k \equiv 1 \pmod {k-1}$).
Thus $k^{n+1} \equiv 1 \pmod {k-1}$ and claim holds

Comment: @alvoutila - Yep, that's prettymuch it.

Comment: This question goes outside of the scope of this "chapter", but here it is: How is it that $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ is equivalent with condition $p \equiv -1 \equiv 11 \pmod {12}$? Maybe something to do with chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Well, $gcd(3,4)=1$ and we know that both 4 and 3 divide $p+1$, so therefore 12 divides $p+1$ (why?).

Comment: I know that if remainders are same then $p \equiv x \pmod {12}$. For example $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ then $p \equiv 1 \pmod {12}$ but would you explain in more detail why $p \equiv -1 \equiv 11 \pmod 12$ if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$

Comment: If $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $gcd(a,b)=1$ and if we have $a\vert c$ and $b \vert c$ for some $c\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $ab \vert c$ (if you're not convinced that this is true, I'd advise taking a bit of time to write down a proof).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $k \equiv 1 \pmod{k-1}$.